# Javascript window open to simulate effect of HTML <a> download attribute

Tags: javascript, html, download

The anchor download attribute is as follows:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/1.mp3" download>Download File</a>
```

This prompts a save/download and does not cause the browser to play the MP3 file.

How do I achieve this if I'm using a function for a button click.

My JS looks like this right now:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/1.mp3');
```

I tried adding `target="_blank"` but in some cases, it opens the file in another tab and starts playing.

Comment: Does this help: [Trigger a file download on click of button Javascript with contents from DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25087107/4642212)? Or why would you need to open a window for downloading?

Comment: Any special reason you are using JavaScript?