# Any way to mimic the download attribute of an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

The `download` attribute of an `<a>` tag helps Edge [open download links more nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002903/how-to-prevent-a-blank-tab-from-appearing-in-edge-when-clicking-on-a-file-link) (i.e. it closes the target tab once it realises it won't be used).  Is there any way to do that when Javascript is responsible for initiating the download?  As in

HTML:

```
<span class='btn-link' onclick='openReport(@orderNumber, @tableBodyId); return false;'>
```

Javascript (talking to ASP.NET MVC controller):

```
function openReport(orderNumber, tableBodyId) {
    var url = "/Reports/ValuationReportDocPdf?orderNumber=" + orderNumber;
    var win = window.open(url, '');
    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087009/trigger-a-file-download-on-click-of-button-javascript-with-contents-from-dom/25087107#25087107

Comment: @chrki - yes, that does the trick for me, thank you! Please submit as an answer, and I'll accept. I also had to detect Edge (because the suggested method didn't work in FF/Chrome), using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002903/how-to-prevent-a-blank-tab-from-appearing-in-edge-when-clicking-on-a-file-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Javascript function or setting that lets you change the filename when downloading, or any that imitates the `download` attribute on `<a>` tags.

In a similar question, [this answer by user3758133](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087107/1781026) outlines a workaround where you programmatically create a link, attach the proper `download` attribute and trigger a click:

```
("#downloadbutton").click(function() {
  //var content = content of file;
  var dl = document.createElement('a');
  dl.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(content));
  dl.setAttribute('download', 'filename.txt');
  dl.click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone's interested, [here are some further details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356146/open-a-pdf-from-edge-without-opening-redundant-blank-tabs/42477576#42477576) on how I implemented this.